# No warning shown in webstorm for Jsdoc mistakes

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

I use webstorm v 10.0.4. I want to use JSDoc in webstorm to verify if there are some mistakes in the objects properties used. I expect the following example showing warning but nothing happen.

In the setting panel, in Editor->Inspections, in Javascript->General, 3 parameters appears when filtered by "jsdoc":

JsDoc  comment matches function signature
Potentially invalid constructor usage
Validate JsDoc /ASDoc

The 3 of them are selected to show warnings

here my example which do not show any warning:

```
/**
*
* @typedef {Object} cleanJRef
*
* @property  {string} rRefName
* @property  {string} rActiveId
* @property  {string} rActiveName
* @property  {string} rDbId
* @property  {string} rDbName
* @property  {Object} rActiveElt
*/

//TODO: why this test do not show a warning or error in webstorm?

/** @type  {cleanJRef} */
var testCleanJRef = {
  rRefName: 1, //should have a warning here
  rActiveId: "0",
  rActiveName: "Name",
  rDbId: "0",
  rDbName: "nom",
  rActiveElt: "new Object()", //should have a warning here
  incorrectProp: "false" //should have a warning here
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no warning for each wrong line but a warning saying: 
"Initializer type {rRefName: number, rActiveId: string..., incorrectProp: string} is not assignable to varialbe type cleanJRef."

I don't know why I did not see it at first...

Answer (score 0):

Type checking is only done when using assignments like `testCleanJRef.rRefName = 1;`. Please vote for [WEB-19342](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19342) to be notified on any progress with it